# How to switch a Laravel app FROM playing audio which is loaded in the browser TO streaming from a cloud hosted audio file?

Tags: javascript, laravel, audio-streaming, wavesurfer.js

Hey everyone how are you today? Hope you're good!!

I have an app that essentially (details not relevant) lets users upload audio and play it in the browser.

I use a library called wavesurfer.js which loads the audio and presents it in a nice way. However wavesurfer uses

```
<src="link to the audio file.mp3">
```

Like most web based media players do.

I am looking to change from this type of behaviour to a new type of behaviour where the audio is streamed from the cloud.

The "why" here is to give both an actual and a perceived increase in the security of the source audio file.

I have googled around a lot and can't seem to find any relevant libraries or tutorials on how to do this. Many articles, even on established sites, refer to "streaming audio" but in fact they are simply playing an audio file which is loaded in the browser.

THE QUESTION

How do you stream an audio file to the browser where the audio file is stored in Amazon S3?

Thanks so much, have a great day.

Comment: In my understanding you want to stream a file from S3 storage instead of the storage folder of your project?  You can define the Storage location where you want to get the file from.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#amazon-s3-compatible-filesystems

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to change from this type of behaviour to a new type of behaviour where the audio is streamed from the cloud.

> Many articles, even on established sites, refer to "streaming audio" but in fact they are simply playing an audio file which is loaded in the browser.

There is a misconception here that the browser is somehow not "streaming".  It is.  The browser will stream the audio data from the server as it requires.  If there is sufficient bandwidth and memory, the browser *may* choose to buffer the whole file.  I assume this is what you're seeing.

> The "why" here is to give both an actual and a perceived increase in the security of the source audio file.

So, you want to use MediaSource Extensions or something?  There is zero security benefit to this.  At best, you can use [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encrypted_Media_Extensions_API), but note that lossless audio is trivially captured.  You'll be creating incompatibility and complexity for really near-zero benefit.  Whether this is required for your use case is up to you to decide.

> How do you stream an audio file to the browser where the audio file is stored in Amazon S3?

You simply sign a URL and load into a media element by setting its `src` attribute.  The browser will make ranged requests when the user seeks.  In the event of connection loss, the browser will reconnect and pick up where it left off.  I also recommend using CloudFront (or any CDN) in front of your bucket.  If you will have a lot of traffic per-resource, be sure to check your URL signing and caching so that your authorized clients are all getting the same URL.

Comment: I want to stream in the way that Soundcloud, Spotify, apple music etc stream. So that you cannot right click and save the source file.

Comment: @Mick They're just using MediaSource Extensions to support HLS playback.  You can do the same thing too if you'd like, but again, there's no security benefit.  You can use EME as I mentioned in my answer, which is the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks @brad. I think the key word in my question was "perceived". My users place an exorbitant value / importance on their audio IP and simply not being able to right click and "save source file as..." is a significant improvement in their perceived assessment of risk. Thanks a lot for your input I'm going to investigate this now, and more likely find a contractor who can implement for me.